# How to increase the resolution of image previews in LyX?

Tags: lyx

I am trying to get higher resolution image previews in LyX, where I embedded images as SVGs.

The result in the editor looks very pixelated and is barely readable. Is there a way to alleviate this?

I suspect the solution may lie in the converter options.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a DPI option the following under the preferences menu, for example

```
inkscape $$i --export-filename=$$0 --export-dpi=200
```

[image]